# Gmail HTML Issues - (mail.google.com)

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

So, I am having quite a few issues when trying to get an HTML email working seamlessly in Gmail.

Issue we are having, not even sure if it's fixable, is on the mail web app version of Gmail and not the app. - mail.google.com.

Once of my HTML emails contains a header (logo, links etc) and will hide and show a second table row for a mobile version.

We use media queries and classes for these table rows, it all works perfectly on: Outlook, Mail, Browser, Android Web just not (mail.google.com).

We had stripped back all of the CSS so the code simply looked like:

```
<tr class="web"> web stuff here </tr> 
<tr class="mobile"> mobile stuff here </tr>
```

With the media queries looking like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:475px) { .web {display: none;} .mobile {display: block} }
```

Now the web mail version ignores all of this and even removes our Style tags and Media queries. So if this is the case, can you even create a responsive email in the web version or is this simply just not supported?

Image below of the broken HTML Email header (600px) With the mobile header below the web version.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L0mz.jpg

Comment: Gmail webmail (as well as the app) support media queries, but they might strip out your style blocks if you have something in there they don't like. Try starting a new style block just for this media query. We can't troubleshoot it more without more of your code.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for this. I did have some research done and did think the same thing so I actually stripped out ALL css apart from my inline code, otherwise I wouldn't be able to actually test the issue. So my media query was the only code I actually had. I did then forward the email to my desktop version to inspect the code, and gmail seems to insert it's own style tags and then has displayed mine underneath it still within the head.

Comment: When you forward emails, it will re-render. So don't expect it to be the same. Each email client has their own way of re-formatting, too. So when testing, are you sending it directly to Gmail webmail? Or forwarding it?